# Verilog code for Clarke and Park transformations

Tags: verilog

I want to write verilog code for Clarke and Park transformations for the implementation of a foc algorithm. I am new to verilog and I am failing to understand how to write the code for such complex equations which involve cos,sin functions and real numbers. Can someone please give me a start? The verilog code I tried to write is below.

```
timescale 1ns/1ps


module clarke_park(iR_i,iY_i,iB_i,theta,iD_o,iQ_o);
output real iD_o;
output real iQ_o;

input real iR_i;
input real iY_i;
input real iB_i;

real k = 0.66;
output real  ialpha;
output real  ibeta;
output real  iY_r;//real part
output real  iY_c;//complex part
output real  iB_r;
output real  iB_c;
output real  ibeta_r;
output real  ibeta_c;

function sin(input real theta);

function cos(input real theta); 

iY_r = -1*(iY_i)*(0.5);
iY_c = (iY_i)*(0.866);
iB_r = -1*(iB_i)*(0.5);
iB_c = -1*(iB_i)*(0.866);

ialpha = k*iR;
ibeta_r = k*(0.866)*(iY_r-iB_r);
ibeta_c = k*(0.866)*(iY_c-iB_c);

real a1 = sin(theta);
real a2 = cos(theta);

iD_r = (a1*(ialpha)) + ((sin(theta))*(ibeta_r));
iD_c = a2*(ibeta_c);
iQ_r = - (1*a2*(ialpha)) + (a1*(ibeta_r));
iQ_c = a1*(ibeta_c);

endfunction


assign iD_o = {iD_r,iD_c};
assign iQ_o = {iQ_r,iQ_c};

endmodule
```

Comment: Could edit the question to include if the result needs to be synthesisable. reals are not synthesisable, if required for FPGA or ASIC rather than just simulation then you will need to use a Floating point core.

Comment: it need not be synthesizable nd it is been developed purely for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this:

```
module clarke_park(
  output real iD_o,
  output real iQ_o,

  input real iR_i,
  input real iY_i,
  input real iB_i,

  output real  ialpha,
  output real  ibeta,
  output real  iY_r,//real part
  output real  iY_c,//complex part
  output real  iB_r,
  output real  iB_c,
  output real  ibeta_r,
  output real  ibeta_c
);

localparam k = 0.66;
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with the functions. but something like:

but note you have not defined `theta`, it was in you port list but then not defined as input or a real.

```
real a1;
real a2;

always @* begin
  iY_r = -1*(iY_i)*(0.5);
  iY_c = (iY_i)*(0.866);
  iB_r = -1*(iB_i)*(0.5);
  iB_c = -1*(iB_i)*(0.866);

  ialpha = k*iR;
  ibeta_r = k*(0.866)*(iY_r-iB_r);
  ibeta_c = k*(0.866)*(iY_c-iB_c);

  a1 = $sin(theta);
  a2 = $cos(theta);

  iD_r = (a1*(ialpha)) + ((sin(theta))*(ibeta_r));
  iD_c = a2*(ibeta_c);
  iQ_r = - (1*a2*(ialpha)) + (a1*(ibeta_r));
  iQ_c = a1*(ibeta_c);
end
```

`$cos` and `$sin` are described in section 20.8 of ieee 1800-2012.

Comment: the fact real numbers are not synthesizable ,so do i need to develop a small verilog module which takes in binary values and then convert them to real values  usable in the above module. i want to use 10 bit inputs for my algorithm but i am unable to understand as to how implement complex no. calculations in verilog.

Comment: You said it was for simulation only, it did not need to be synthesizable?